# Redux - How to partially populate initialState from localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to manage store in my application. So, I have the following state model;

```
RootState {
    teams: {
        teamBySomeId: {}
        virtualTeamById: {}
    }
}
```

And I am attempting to synchronize the store and `localStorage`. **However**, it's just `virtualTeamById` that I want to sync. Therefore, the state that is saved into `localStorage` is as following;

```
teamsVirtualState: '{teams: {virtualTeamById: {"50": "Some data"}}}'
```

And when I load the `localStorage` value to the application on startup, everything runs fine and the `preloadedState` is populated with above.

Now, I have the following selectors for the said state, which is as following;

```
export const teamByIdSelector = (id: number) => (state: RootState): ITeam => state.teams.teamBySomeId[id];
export const virtualTeamByIdSelector = (id: number) => (state: RootState): IVirtualTeam => state.teams.virtualTeamById[id];
```

This is where it goes **wrong!** It seems like redux is expecting `teamBySomeId` to exist, and by restoring the state **partially** above, I have mutated the `teams` state object to be a different model.

Here is the error that typescript gives back on **teamByIdSelector** ;

> TypeError: Cannot read property '176' of undefined

Is there any preferred approach on how we should manage synchronous process between `localStorage` and redux store? Or do I always need to save the entire store object into the `localStorage`?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

Code for the synchronize mechanism;

```
/**
 * @description Mapping relation between synchronous mechanism between redux store and localStorage
 * @description Format is { storageKey: storePath }
 * @summary Add more field if there is more thing to sync store between the app and client
 * 
 * @field storageKey The key that will be used to save the store into localStorage
 * @field storePath The path where the store object is located
 */
const storeStorageMap: { [storageKey: string]: string } = {
  "teamsVirtualTeam": "teams.virtualTeamById"
};

export const createStore = (initialState: any = {}, localStorage?: boolean) => {
  if (localStorage && window && window.localStorage) {
    const storageState: { [key: string]: any } = {};

    /** Loads value from localStorage */
    for (const storageKey in storeStorageMap) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(storeStorageMap, storageKey)) {
        const storePath = storeStorageMap[storageKey],
          rawValue = window.localStorage.getItem(storageKey);

        if (storePath && rawValue) {
          try {
            const jsonValue = JSON.parse(rawValue);
            _.set(storageState, storePath, jsonValue);
          }
          catch(err) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /** Extends initialState with storageState */
    initialState = _.merge(initialState, storageState);
  }

  console.log({initialState});

  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false,
      }).concat(logger),
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    preloadedState: initialState || {},
  });
};

const store = createStore({}, true);

/**
 * Subscribe to event whenever dispatch is being called
 */
store.subscribe(() => {
  const combinedState = store.getState();

  console.log({combinedState});

  /**
   * Persists value of virtualTeamById to localStorage
   */
  if (window && window.localStorage) {
    for (const storageKey in storeStorageMap) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(storeStorageMap, storageKey)) {
        const storePath = storeStorageMap[storageKey],
          storeValue = _.get(combinedState, storePath);

        if (storeValue && !_.isEmpty(storeValue)) {
          window.localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(storeValue));
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How about initializing the `teamBySomeId` as an empty array? As I understand, your initial state is missing default values for this field which eventually cause the "Cannot read property ... of undefined"

Comment: @dongnhan Thanks for the suggestion! You meant as an empty object. And yes, that will work. However, the sample above is just one of the state - and I am intending to sync in multiple states. I am looking more into generic approach to ease up scalability. But currently, I am exporting all `initialState` of my states and I think I will put the model all in `localStorage` but only the selective one that's populated.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant as an empty object, your states are flatten. Here's one solution that I come up with. The idea is that you will create 1 `appDefaultState` object which is your entire state tree populated with default values (ex: empty object, empty array...). After that, in `createStore`, you patch this `appDefaultState` by the data provided by `initialState` and the states from `localStorage`. So the final value provided to `preloadedState` is computed from `appDefaultState`, `initialState` and states from `localStorage`